# Scrapy CrawlSpider: URL depth

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to implement same functionality as ScreamingFrog has – measure the url depth. 
To do this, I'm accessing depth param of response.meta, just like this: `response.meta.get('depth', 0)`, but the results I get differs a lot from the results of ScreamingFrog. 
Thus I wanted to debug why this happens this, by saving *all of the pages that CrawlSpider went through, in order to get to the current page.*

This is how my current spider looks like:

```
class FrSpider(scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider):
    """Designed to crawl french version of dior.com"""

    name = 'Fr'
    allowed_domains = [website]
    denyList = []

    start_urls = ['https://www.%s/' % website]
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=denyList), follow=True, callback='processLink'),)

    def processLink(self, response):
        link = response.url
        depth = response.meta.get('depth', 0)
        print('%s: depth is %s' % (link, depth))
```

Here comparison of crawling stats(same website, limited to first ~500 pages) between my crawler & screamingfrog:

```
Depth(Clicks from Start Url)  Number of Urls  % of Total
1                             62              12.4
2                             72              14.4
3                             97              19.4
4                             49              9.8
5                             40              8.0
6                             28              5.6
7                             46              9.2
8                             50              10.0
9                             56              11.2
----------------------------  --------------  ----------
```

vs

[image: screaming frog]

As you can see it differs a lot, and by extending the crawl from first 500 pages to full website shows a huge discrepancy between two approaches.

I was wondering if someone could either point out to me mistake I'm doing, or help me with advice on how could I store all the pages crawler went through, to get to the current page. 
Visualization would look like this: 
[image: website tree]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out issue was in the [scrapy's default crawling order](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/faq.html#does-scrapy-crawl-in-breadth-first-or-depth-first-order). By changing it from DFO to BFO I get expected stats.

Answer (score 0):

You could try DEPTH_STATS_VERBOSE ( in settings ), then check if both results are equal.

Comment: By enabling `DEPTH_STATS_VERBOSE` I can see that stats returned by CrawlSpider ±matches my own stats(that I calculate myself), but not screamingfrog.